# Left join using IS NULL does not work in DB2?

Tags: sql, oracle, db2

I am trying to left join to tables using a query like this

```
SELECT * FROM table1 a, table2 b WHERE (a.ID = b.ID OR b.ID IS NULL)
```

In Oracle, this is equivalent to a `LEFT JOIN` (and in other databases as well, afaik).

Doing the same thing in DB2 (z/OS) produces an inner join - the `b.ID IS NULL` clause has no effect on the result, removing it does not change anything.

Is there a way to make this work in DB2? Is this something that should work according to ANSI SQL?

PS: I am aware that I can use the `JOIN` syntax, I'm just interested in why this doesn't work and if there is a way around this.

Comment: Your query is not equivalent to `LEFT JOIN`. With Oracle you can use `(+)` instead of `LEFT JOIN` like this: `SELECT * FROM table1 a, table2 b where a.ID = b.ID (+)`

Comment: Your statement is ***NOT*** equivalent to a `LEFT JOIN` in Oracle.

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
SELECT a.*, b.*
  FROM tbl1 a LEFT JOIN tbl2 b ON a.id=b.id;
```